# How to move widget area to another section in WordPress Customizer

Tags: widgets, theme-customizer

I'm trying to move a widget area I have set up. It automatically displays in the Customizer's "Widgets" panel as it should but I would like to move it to another section that I have added in another panel. So far, the below code is the closest I've found but unfortunately it causes an error in debug mode. Is there a way around this or another way of doing it?

```
add_action( 'customize_register', 'wpse210938_move_widget_area' );
function wpse210938_move_widget_area () {
    global $wp_customize;
    $wp_customize->get_section ('sidebar-widgets-wpse210938_area')->panel = 'wpse210938_panel';
    }
```

Comment: I would not recommend doing this. It will likely have unexpected side effects and there wouldn't be guarantees that it would continue to work in the future.

Comment: Thanks @weston Do you know of any other way of accomplishing this? Do you know if it has ever been discussed for core? I think it would be a great feature. Widget areas can be added anywhere to a theme but forcing them all to one section of the Customizer seems a bit limiting to me.

Comment: The only thing that comes to mind is to add a dummy section that when expanded will then expand the widget section instead. So it would be like a section shortcut.

Comment: That's interesting @weston Do you know how to go about doing that?